# htaccess on codeigniter folder supports user-logged status

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to protect the upload-folder in my codeigniter project.

In this upload-folder is a sub-folder for every user of my project
Example

```
uploads/user1
uploads/user2
```

Now I want to make sure that there is only a single way to access if the user is logged in.

So I edit with htaccess files
for the upload/

```
# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes
```

And for the sub-user-folders

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

But it wont work. One time I have no access to all or at the other hand I can access all...

Is it possible to know, what I'm doing wrong or is there a better way to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As you are setting up permission to all, these changes can affect all directory. You should try to code for change only one directory.

Comment: If you want to separate users file then you should try to upload it to the database(if the file is not larger).

Comment: they are all kind of files including large video files, so storeing in database seem no good way

Comment: then you should personally store the files above the root or in a secure location, and then have an access script (such as fetch_file.php) with a unique identifier in the URL (e.g. fetch_file.php?uid=1234).

If the user is authorized to access the file with the unique id of 1234; provide the file from the location details within the database, otherwise deny the request.

This way, the user can not access the file without the correct permissions, as it is stored securely above the root which should not be accessible from the internets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the comment from Rohit Bhadani

I've store the files now outside the root httpdocs folder.

In my project i use a file to check the authorization of the user for this file and after that the accessfile will outputt the called file to the user.